# Logistic regression with grouped data

Tags: logistic, python

Likely a simple question, have searched for an answer I promise!

I'm looking to do a Logistic regression for a dataset in which data is grouped by an ID, where there is one positive flag per group and the groups vary in size. A simple example would be a prediction of who is the heaviest in a group of individuals, given their age and height:

```
| GroupId | Age | Height | Heaviest |
|---------|-----|--------|----------|
| 1       | 27  | 198    | 1        |
| 1       | 42  | 165    | 0        |
| 1       | 34  | 133    | 0        |
| 2       | 63  | 176    | 1        |
| 2       | 27  | 189    | 0        |
| 2       | 55  | 165    | 0        |
| 2       | 44  | 166    | 0        |
```

My question is how we can leverage the grouping information into a logistic regression, as many of the positive flags will be on individuals who shouldn't be characterised as 'Heaviest' in a global sense, or am I thinking about it the wrong way? For what it's worth, I'm working with python's statsmodels library.

Comment: The best way is to perform the analysis for each group separately because `heaviest` is not a globally applicable variable.

Comment: It looks to me like a dataset appropriate for a conditional logit model (similar to multinomial logit) where each group is a choice set. (It's not yet available in statsmodels except for a unfinished pull request.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment - will look into this, haven't come across it before

Comment: Pylogit is a python lib that does conditional logit regression. It solves your problem perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

So after searching through leads kindly provided by this thread I've concluded that a Cox proportional hazards model would probably be the most appropriate, as this allows for stratification of the data by an ID as above.

For the curious, I came across [lifelines](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/lifelines/blob/master/lifelines/fitters/coxph_fitter.py) for python which has a good implementation and have been doing some moderately successful tests with it.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I believe Group ID will not make any sense as weight(heaviest) does't depend on group ID. ( Although no of person in a group will be useful). This can be one way to include the information.

Even if you want to directly include dummy variable Group ID, it will through out some model but what will you predict then ?